# How to create non-inline text in ModernCV?

Tags: xetex, moderncv

Here is currently what the education section looks like.

[image: ModernCV]

I want to be able to add the education text, without the bullet point. This is the current code:

```
\cventry{Aug 2010 -- May 2014}{B.S. Computer Engineering}{University}{State City}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Relevant Coursework: Fundamental Algorithms, Digital Signal Processing, Integrated Circuit Design, Machine Learning
\end{itemize}}
```

I tried this to no avail:

```
\cventry{Aug 2010 -- May 2014}{B.S. Computer Engineering}{University}{State City}{}{
    Relevant Coursework: Fundamental Algorithms, Digital Signal Processing, Integrated Circuit Design, Machine Learning }
```

Comment: With : `\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{red}
\begin{document}
\section{Education}
\cventry{Aug 2010 -- May 2014}{B.S. Computer Engineering}{University}{State City}{}{
Relevant Coursework: Fundamental Algorithms, Digital Signal Processing, Integrated Circuit Design, Machine Learning
}
\end{document}`, I get this http://i.stack.imgur.com/ifQGX.png . So you have to give complete code that does not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here (which one to use might depend on the desired result):

1. Use an empty optional argument for `\item`.
2. Redefine `\labelitemi` (locally) to be empty.
3. Don't use an `itemize` environment at all.

The following example illustrates these approaches:

```
\documentclass{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{red} 

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\begin{document} 

\section{Education} 
\cventry{Aug 2010 -- May 2014}{B.S. Computer Engineering}{University}{State City}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item[] Relevant Coursework: Fundamental Algorithms, Digital Signal Processing, Integrated Circuit Design, Machine Learning
\end{itemize}}

\cventry{Aug 2010 -- May 2014}{B.S. Computer Engineering}{University}{State City}{}{
  {
  \renewcommand\labelitemi{}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Relevant Coursework: Fundamental Algorithms, Digital Signal Processing, Integrated Circuit Design, Machine Learning
  \end{itemize}
  }
}

\cventry{Aug 2010 -- May 2014}{B.S. Computer Engineering}{University}{State City}{}{ Relevant Coursework: Fundamental Algorithms, Digital Signal Processing, Integrated Circuit Design, Machine Learning }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I went with the third option, works perfectly for me!